# SweetAlert with type of "input" still runs if user clicks cancel

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

So I'm using [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/), and am offering the opportunity to add an extra short message to a user's request. The problem I have is that even if the user clicks the 'Cancel' button, it still makes the post request (removed from the example below) within the function().

```
swal({
    title: "Request!",
    text: "Add a message to your request if you wish...",
    type: "input",
    showCancelButton: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: true,
    inputPlaceholder: "Short message..."
}, function(inputValue) {
   // this is always run, regardless of if the user clicks cancel
});
```

I could probably workaround this by forcing a message to be entered, then I can wrap the post request in an `if` statement on the `inputValue` value, however this must be optional.

Please also note that I'd prefer to stick to the version of SweetAlert that I linked to above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inputValue` parameter that the callback takes is `false` if the user hits cancel, and `true` if they don't. So the way to disable the callback if the user hits cancel is to check for the existence of `inputValue` in the callback.

```
swal({
    title: "Request!",
    text: "Add a message to your request if you wish...",
    type: "input",
    showCancelButton: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: true,
    inputPlaceholder: "Short message..."
}, function(inputValue) {
   if (inputValue) {
      // the user didn't hit cancel
   }
});
```

Comment: Update: the change actually had to be `if(inputValue !== false)`